# In Mongoengine, how to have an embedded document with a reference to the parent document type^

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am developping an API in Python with Flask and Mongoengine. I want to have the following structure:

```
class FactionRelationship (Document):
    faction = ReferenceField('Faction')
    relationship = IntField()

class Faction (Document):
    name = StringField(required=True)
    relationships = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(FactionRelationship))
```

But Mongoengine spews out the following error: `mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: Invalid embedded document class provided to an EmbeddedDocumentField` but I'm not sure how to do it then. How then can I create an embedded document that has a reference to it's parent document type? It can not reference the parent document, just other documents of the parent type.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. Changing `Document` to `EmbeddedDocument` in the `FactionRelationship` class did the trick.